# Grafana Status Panel Plugin - genereate status box for each entry from a Prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to create a dashboard out of `process_uptime_seconds{namespace="$namespace"}` query from Spring Actuator and Prometheus as datasource.

I am trying to build a single stat box menus that will show the status, but for each value from the request. So instead of singlestat I have tried using Status Panel. However I keep getting a single box generated. How can I create dynamically a separate box for each entry from the returned object?

Answer (score 0):

So far I have upgraded from 6.6 to 7 and switched to the new Stat panel that managed to visualize properly. The limitation I was trying to avoid is that I can't  control fonts.